# Using a delegate for value transformation

Tags: c#, methods, .net-3.5, delegates, transformation

I want to develop a basic class that holds a string value and I want to pass a transformation rule how this value should be stored as an int value.

When I'm not completely wrong this should be possible using some kind of delegate. Unfortunately I have no idea how to begin and what to search the internet for.

Here a simple example:

```
    class MyClass
    {
      public string InputString { get; private set; }
      public int OutputValue { get; set; }
      public MyClass(string inputString)
      {
        this.InputString = inputString;
      }

      //I suspect that I need a method here taking some kind of delegate?
    }

    MyClass mC = new MyClass("abcd");

    //here I now want to pass something to mC saying that each character should 
    // be transformed to its ascii value and be added to a total value

    //or another object should transform abcd interpreting it hexadecimal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like a [`Func<string, int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx):

```
Func<string, int> converter = (theString) => int.Parse(theString);
```

Then have your type take a `Func<string, int>`, possibly in the constructor, and call it when you need to convert:

```
converter(InputString);
```

The implementation of this delegate can be whatever you like, so long as it takes a `string` and returns an `int`.

A possible way (not demonstrating specifically the ASCII value of each character):

```
class MyClass
{
    private Func<string, int> _valueConverter;

  public string InputString { get; private set; }
  public int OutputValue { get { return _valueConverter(InputString); } }

  public MyClass(string inputString, Func<string, int> valueConverter)
  {
    _valueConverter = valueConverter;
    this.InputString = inputString;
  }
}

// As a lambda
MyClass mC = new MyClass("2", input => int.Parse(input));
```

You can supply something to fulfil the `Func` parameter as either a lambda expression as I show above, or a method group:

```
private static int AMethodThatMatchesTheFuncSignature(string value)
{
    return 42;
}

var mC = new MyClass("2", AMethodThatMatchesTheFuncSignature);
```

If you have never seen it before, `Func<T1, T2>` is just a pre-made delegate provided by the framework (there are loads of `Func` and `Action` types defined for no arguments up to many arguments. `Action` all return void and `Func` all return the final defined type `TResult`).

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I'll go for the Func-constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You may add a Transform method that takes a delegate and apply on InputString:

```
class MyClass
{
  public string InputString { get; private set; }
  public int OutputValue { get; set; }
  public MyClass(string inputString)
  {
    this.InputString = inputString;
  }

  public void Transform(Func<string, int> f){
    OutputValue = f(InputString);
  }
}

MyClass mC = new MyClass("abcd");
mC.Transform(c=> c.Sum(c=> ((int)c));//OutputValue is changed
mC.Transform(c=> (int)c.Average(c=> ((int)c));//OutputValue is changed
```

Comment: This is the closest answer to what I wanted to achieve. But I prefer it using the constructor I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the design pattern "[strategy](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx)" to "delegate" the implementation of an algorithm.

(Without error handling)

```
interface IConverter
{
    int Convert(string value);
}

class ASCIConverter : IConverter
{
    public int Convert(string value)
    {
        //conversion implementation here
    }
}

class MyClass
{

    string Input;
    IConverter Converter;
    public MyClass(string input, IConverter converter)
    {
        this.Input = input;
        this.Converter = converter;
    }

    public int GetConvertedValue()
    {
        return this.Converter.Convert(this.Input);
    }

}
```

**[Edit]**
From calling code:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass("abcd",new ASCIConverter());
int intRepresentation = myClass.GetConvertedValue();
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the pattern. I'm going to think about it.